# multiple glitches in rendered rasterfile after reprojecting in QGIS

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, wgs84, raster-conversion, natural-earth

I reprojected a natural earth raster file ([Natural Earth II with Shaded Relief, Water, and Drainages](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-natural-earth-2/10m-natural-earth-2-with-shaded-relief-water-and-drainages/), CRS WGS84) with a costum CRS (azimuthal orthografic) using *Raster->Projections->Warp* in QGIS. Worked fine except glitches at the international date line and at the horizon of the hemisphere (see attached image). An idea how I can prevent these?

Edit: as @user30184 suggests adding `-wo SAMPLE_STEPS=100` and `-wo SOURCE_EXTRA=10` fixes the glitches

[image]

Comment: Try warping options `-wo SAMPLE_STEPS=100` and perhaps `-wo SOURCE_EXTRA=10` http://www.gdal.org/structGDALWarpOptions.html

Comment: @user30184 - Please post your _comment_ as an **answer** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `-wo SAMPLE_STEPS=100` and `-wo SOURCE_EXTRA=10` fixes the glitches, thanks to @user30184